# JPA Web application management strategies

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

We're currently developing a J2EE web app using JPA as our data access layer. We're currently entertaining a couple different strategies to utilizing caching within our applications.

1. Create an `EntityManager` per request

   - Get caching within the request scope, but lose the cache at the end of the request
   - Makes it easy to rollback any changes from an entire request
2. Create an `EntityManager` per Http Session

   - Get caching within the session scope
   - Makes things more complicated with transactions, would have to create a new transaction per request, then would be able to rollback changes per request

I've seen both strategies in the Hibernate documentation. My question is which is more widely used and if we do the `EntityManager` per session, will we run into synchronization issues by using the same `EntityManager` across different request threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more widely used approach is to create an `EntityManager` per request. However this should remain hidden from you. You should use some dependency-injection mechanism (spring/CDI/EJB) that will inject the proper `EntityManager` where `@PersistenceContext` is placed.

If you are interested how this is achieved in the common case where your beans are some sort singletons (one stateless bean / one spring bean of scope singleton) - the container actually injects a proxy in the target object. And each time the proxy is consulted, it gets the *current* `EntityManager` instance, which is (in the case of spring at least) bound to a `ThreadLocal` (= request in this case)

**Update:** If you want to implement this functionality in a home-grown framework, then use cglib / javassist / JDK proxy and inject it where `@PersistenceContext` is placed. A request = thread. On each request that needs data access, create a new `EntityManager` and store it in a `ThreadLocal`. Remember to clean it in the end because servlet containers reuse threads. From the proxy you can obtain the current `ThreadLocal` value.

But in case you are not far into the project, then I'd suggest moving to something more stable, like spring, cdi or guice.

Comment: We have a home grown ioc container built around the Stripes mvc framework that we're currently using to inject the EntityManager into the places that we need. But this answers my question, we were leaning toward per request but just wanted to check with the rest of the world.

Answer (score 0):

What server are you using?  It should be able to inject an EntityManger for you rather than requiring the application deal with it.

Comment: Glassfish v2 (IT requirement). Out of curiosity, if the Entity Manager is injected, will the app server create a new entity manager per injection? or will is it configurable to re-use one per request or session?

Comment: I've used the injection on Glassfish v2.  Any J2EE5 server should do it.  I'm not sure how it creates the classes specifically.  I would assume it uses a pool just like the database connections.