# Potential Issues with creating EntityManager per HttpSession in web application

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, servlets, jakarta-ee

In one of the application ,I saw Entity Manager is created 'per user HttpSession' and EntityManagerFactory is created only once.

Spring or EJB is NOT used in application.
Entity manager is cached in http session and closed when session invalidated.

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager() { 
    //Logic to get entity manger from session
    //If its present , then return 
    //Else create new one , entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    //Put it into session and then return.
    //Returned entity manager is not closed by dao methods , 
    //but clear() is invoked
}
```

1. What are potential problems with this design.
2. What if 100K Users logged in into application simultaneously, will we run out of jdbc connections ?
3. Does every entity manager has a separate JDBC connection associated with it?

Comment: It reminds http://www.benmccann.com/hibernate-with-jpa-annotations-and-guice/ example where EntityManager is stored as ThreadLocal. Related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418979/jpa-web-application-management-strategies

Comment: Are you really using full Java EE, or just a servlet container such as Tomcat?

Comment: Just servlet container tomcat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to 2 and 3 is yes. As for Q1:

One problem you will have is that sessions typically last anywhere from 2 to 24 hours (or more) after they were last accessed. This means that your session object will try to sustain the EntityManager open and the EntityManager will try to keep the JDBC connection alive and exclusive to itself. Even with 50 users per hour, you'll already have loads of exceptions and Error 500 pages because of this.

I believe Serge Ballesta listed the other major problems this approach will cause.

A much safer solution is to have a static `ThreadLocal<EntityManager>` singleton access and a `javax.servlet.Filter` on all URLs with a try-finally statement that makes sure the EntityManager is properly closed on each request. Otherwise any exception that might occur will leave the connection dangling and cause additional problems.

Answer (score 8):

Please do not do that: you are tying the persistence layer directly in the web layer when best practices recommend to design layered applications with (loose) links only between one layer and only the adjacent one.

For the real problems that can arise with such a design, one is memory wasting. As HTTP is a non connected protocol, if a client only closes his/her browser without an explicit disconnection, the session will not be immediately be closed and will only be collected by session timeout. That's why best practices recommend to store as few objects possible in session and as small as possible. By the way, if you want to serve the application on a farm of servers, objects stored in session should be serializable, and I am unsure whether an entity manager is. At least it is not guaranteed by its interface definition.

I have seen such a design in an old application using Hibernate, where the Hibernate session (more or less equivalent to an EntityManager) was stored in the http session. The rational behind it was that as the HibernateSession contained a cache, it could speed up the application. The actual result was that the application required plenty of memory to only support several hundred users and will never be scalable to thousands user without complete rewriting.

I know I only answered the 1 question here because but I really think that the jdbc connections question is not the major one. The Hibernate experiment showed that we could manage the problem of jdbc session by tweaking Tomcat's pool to soon recycle jdbc connections and of course increasing the pool size but to an acceptable limit. Because I suppose that major EntityManager implementations are able to automatically ask for a new jdbc session when their's comes to be closed (as a Hibernate session do).